# Propagate event from custom control to form

Tags: c#, wpf, events, custom-controls

I have a custom control like:

```
public sealed class BorderEx : Control
{
    public static readonly RoutedEvent ReloadClickEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ReloadClick", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(BorderEx));

    public event RoutedEventHandler ReloadClick
    {
        add { AddHandler(ReloadClickEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(ReloadClickEvent, value); }
    }

    void RaiseReloadClickEvent()
    {
        var newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(ReloadClickEvent);
        RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
    }

    static BorderEx()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(BorderEx), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(BorderEx)));
    }
}
```

and there is event rised on reloadButton click at generic.xaml

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type cbr:BorderEx}">

<ControlTemplate.Triggers>

    <Trigger SourceName="reloadButton" Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="reloadButton" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        <EventSetter Event="ReloadClick" Handler="RaiseReloadClickEvent"></EventSetter>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>

</ControlTemplate
```

But I have no idea how to raise this external event from internal button. Spend last few hours googling and ended up with nothing. above EventSetter is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part was ok,

```
    public static readonly RoutedEvent ReloadClickEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ReloadClick", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(BorderEx));

    public event RoutedEventHandler ReloadClick
    {
        add { AddHandler(ReloadClickEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(ReloadClickEvent, value); }
    }

    static BorderEx()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(BorderEx), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(BorderEx)));
    }
```

I had to create dependency property, so I can change some value on click event

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ReloadProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Reload", typeof (bool), typeof (BorderEx), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), ReloadClicked));
    public bool Reload
    {
        get { return (bool) GetValue(ReloadProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ReloadProperty, value); }
    }
```

and I can handle it in additional method triggered on change

```
    private static void ReloadClicked(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!((bool) e.NewValue)) return;
        var sender = (BorderEx) o;
        sender.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ReloadClickEvent));
    }
```

then it just changing value on click was needed

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger SourceName="reloadButton" Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="reloadButton" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        <Setter Property="Reload" Value="True"/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your event looks great, but the fact that `EventSetter` can not be set in the trigger. Quote from [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c0e99261-ec01-46ac-ad59-af61254d3ffd/event-handler-in-the-eventsetter-throwing-xamlparseexception):

> Because using EventSetter to wire up event handler is a compile-time feature which is plumbed through IStyleConnector interface, there is another interface called IComponentConnector which is used by the XAML compiler to wire up event handler for standalone XAML elements.

You can do this. Identify `EventSetter` outside trigger, such as in the early `Style` / `Template`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:BorderEx}">
    <EventSetter Event="Button.Click" Handler="ReloadClickEvent" />

...

</Style>
```

`Code behind`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }        

    private void ReloadClickEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseEvent(new DemoEventArgs(BorderEx.ReloadClickEvent, sender));
    }
}

public class DemoEventArgs : RoutedEventArgs
{
    public DemoEventArgs(RoutedEvent routedEvent, object source) : base(routedEvent, source)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Raise!");
    }
}

public sealed class BorderEx : Control
{
    public static readonly RoutedEvent ReloadClickEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ReloadClick", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(BorderEx));

    public event RoutedEventHandler ReloadClick
    {
        add { AddHandler(ReloadClickEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(ReloadClickEvent, value); }
    }

    private void RaiseReloadClickEvent()
    {
        var newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(ReloadClickEvent);
        RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
    }

    static BorderEx()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(BorderEx), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(BorderEx)));
    }
}
```

Or alternatively, use the `DependencyProperty` (can also be *attached*). Example:

Property definition:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SampleProperty =
                                          DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Sample",
                                          typeof(bool),
                                          typeof(SampleClass),
                                          new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnSample));

private static void OnSample(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue is bool && ((bool)e.NewValue) == true)
    {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

Calling in XAML.

In `EventTrigger`:

```
<EventTrigger SourceName="MyButton" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(local:SampleClass.Sample)">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

Using with `DataTrigger` (in `Style`/`DataTemplate`/`etc`):

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyBox, Path=Status), Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="(local:SampleClass.Sample)" Value="True" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Using with `Trigger` (in `Style`):

```
<Trigger Property="MyCheckBox.IsChecked" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="(local:SampleClass.Sample)" Value="True" />
</Trigger>
```

Using behind code:

```
private void Clear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SampleClass.SetSampleClass(MyBox, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, saying that is not doable as I wanted and providing all details and ideas above allowed me to find own solution.